How bad re-hashing can cost?
Lets assume that the load factor of a hash table of size $n$ became inappropriate.
The process of re-hashing involves choosing a new hash function.
A good choice of a new function will make the cost of the process $\Theta(n)$.
I'm failing to see, but is there exists a poor choice for a new hash function that can lead the cost of the re-hashing process to $\Theta(n^{2})$ ?
If so, one can give a concreate example ?

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164822/why-hastables-rehash-complexity-may-be-quadratic-in-worst-case

The $\Theta(n)$ is the number of hash operations. You can create a horribly bad hash operation, but the number of awfully slow operations would still be $\Theta(n)$.

This isn't true if you expand your scope beyond only counting the number of hash invocations, if you use linear probing and your new hash choice was $h(x) = 0$, the re-hash operation would take $O(n^2)$ due to all the moves.

@orlp I want to be sure I understood what you wrote: lets say I indeed use linear probing and let's say all the values in the original table were 0. When I will re-hash to a bigger table, the cost of the re-hashing will be: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}O(i)=O(n^2)$$
